# Can I run a node.js script from another directory? Using absolute path to script

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

Friends

I am using `node` to do automated testing using `Appium`

The tests run from a bash script that changes the current directory

The path to the test is absolute.

Given that the path to the script is: `/Users/bob/appium/test.js` and the current directory (from the POV of bash) is `/Users/bob/wd/`

I get the error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/bob/wd/test.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

It is true `Error: Cannot find module '/Users/bob/wd/test.js'` that file does not exist.

I am not used to node, I am not sure I can even do this.

Why is it looking in the current directory for ?

The contents of the script is:

```
// Empty test for debugging the rest of the system
"use strict"

async function main () {
    console.log("Here I am")

}
main().catch(console.log);
```

There is a lot of stuff going on in my script, the role of this JS file (/Users/bob/appium/test.js) is not run any tests, but to let the rest of the framework do its thing.

Comment: `require('../wd/test.js')` ?

Comment: `node /Users/bob/appium/test.js` ?